# Give an example in which two events exhibit conditional independence with an event B but not with B complement.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, independence

Are there any examples of events A and B such that P(A∩B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C) but not with C'?
Especially with dice or coins? or is there any specific example?

Comment: No idea what you are asking.

Comment: compliment $\to$ complement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 An example of events exhibiting conditional independence with event C but not with its complement ie C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an urn with two balls, black and white. You also have a fair coin. You flip the coin, and then...

- If the result is heads, you draw two balls from the urn with replacement.
- If the result is tails, you draw two balls form the urn without replacement.

Let $C$ be the event the coin is heads, let $A$ be the event the first ball you draw is white, and let $B$ be the event that the second balls is black. Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$, but $A$ and $B$ are conditionally dependent given $\overline C$.

Comment: Am I correct in calculating that,
P(A∩B|C)= 1/4=1/2.1/2= P(A|C)P(B|C)
but P(A∩B|C')= 1/2 
but what is the value of  P(A|C').P(B|C') is it 1/4?

Comment: Your comment is correct on all counts. $P(A\mid C')\cdot P(B\mid C')=(1/2)(1/2)=1/4$.